# Copy files and do not overwrite

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

this code is working excellent for me. But I have files with the same names and its not copy them. Can someone please please tell how I can do it and modify it.

```
@echo off
mkdir c:\test 
dir C:\Users\Administrator\*.html /b /s > c:\test\output.txt 
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\test\output.txt) DO copy "%%a" "C:\Test"
```

So my goal is if he founds home.html existing the next one that he will find to be home1.html, home.blabla, whatever just to not loose the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround for the task.  It adds a random number to each filename.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
mkdir "c:\test"
dir "C:\Users\Administrator\*.html" /b /s /a-d > "c:\test\output.txt"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\test\output.txt") DO copy "%%a" "C:\Test\%%~na - !random!!random!%%~xa"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to create a `for` cycle that calls subroutines, as in the following example:

> @echo off
>
> set /p FOLDER_1="Path to Folder n.1: "
> set /p FOLDER_2="Path to Folder n.2: "
>   dir "%FOLDER_1%" /a:-d /b > output.txt
>
> for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (output.txt) do (
> cd "%FOLDER_2%"
> if exist
>   %%a (
> call :TRUE %%a
> ) else (
> copy "%FOLDER_1%\%%a" ".\%%a"
> )
> )
> goto
>   :EOF
>
> :TRUE
> set NUM=1
> :TRUE_SUBLABEL
> set "FILENAME=%~n1_%NUM%%~x1"
> set /a
>   NUM=%NUM%+1
> if exist "%FILENAME%" (
> goto TRUE_SUBLABEL
> ) else (
> copy
>   "%FOLDER_1%\%1" ".\%FILENAME%"
> )
> goto EOF
>
> :EOF
> pause

Calling subroutines from the `for` cycle allows to set a `goto` statement inside them, which is necessary to create an increasing value in the filename. This is not possible using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`.

EDIT: I have added in the first lines two `set` statements to set the folders this Batch script is going to deal with during the execution; all this make the script more clear and comprehensible. Of course, if you don't need it, just set the path directly in the code lines.